# Prevent Python from showing entered input

Tags: python, input

In Python when I change the value of a variable through raw_input in the terminal it would write a new line stating its new value. I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid that because straight after user's input there is a print function which uses the value received before. In the end the user will get both values: original and modified while for the purpose of my program he only has to see the modified.

I use IDLE to write my scripts and then execute them in terminal.

**Update**

A simple example would be the following. The input is string "Hello" and the output should be "Me: Hello". There should be no "Hello" before the final result.

```
a = raw_input()
print ("Me: " + a)
```

And the output should be just

```
Me: Hello
```

rather than

```
Hello
Me: Hello
```

Comment: Could you post the output you are getting and the output you are wanting?

Comment: Show the actual code you're referring to - it isn't clear exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want user to see the input, just mute `sys.stdout` (it's a bit hack tho):

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import sys
>>> orig_out = sys.stdout
>>> print 'give me input: ',
give me input: 
>>> sys.stdout = StringIO()
>>> a = raw_input('')
string I type
>>> sys.stdout = orig_out
>>> a
>>> 'string I type'
```

...and if you put this into a function then it's exactly what you want!

a.py

```
....

def foo():
    orig_out = sys.stdout
    print 'give me input: ',
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    a = raw_input()
    sys.stdout = orig_out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

running:

```
yed@rublan $ ~ python a.py

give me input: something I type!!!!!

yed@rublan $ ~
```

Comment: I already tried using this function but the problem is that the user can't see text he is typing before submission.

Comment: what about this hack with `stdout`? .)

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: so what?! have you tried the code I put into my answer earlier? It works exactly as you want

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but here is a Python 2+3 solution (with a small improvement):

In `prompt_demo.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import io
import sys

import six.moves


def prompt(msg):
    print(msg, end=u'')
    orig_out = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
        return six.moves.input(msg)
    finally:
        sys.stdout = orig_out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = prompt(u"Give me input: ")
    print(u"Do you mean '{0}'?".format(text))
```

- This solution uses `io.StringIO`, which is the Python 2+3 compatible.
- It also uses the `six` library to backport the `raw_input` function (which is renamed `input` in Python 3).
- The `try` ... `finally` solution is better in case of exception during the input: it restores the original value of `sys.stdout`.

I also want to point the nice solution available in the [`Click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) library. Here is a demo:

```
import click

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = click.prompt(u"Give me input: ", prompt_suffix='')
    click.echo(u"Do you mean '{0}'?".format(text))
```

See the documentation about [`click.prompt`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/prompts/#input-prompts).

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to do difficult things like that, the answser is really simple:

```
chat_respond="you say: "+input("Write here to respond: ")
#i will suppose that you want to write hello
#That will display:
Write here to respond: hello
```

Because automaticaly the input is printed, it will show the string of the variable but you add something before the input so it will print that plus the input

```
you say: hello
```

You don't need to use difficult librairies or modify a module, just to add to the variable before you stock the input, you can also do that:

```
chat_respond="you say: "
chat_respond+=input("Write here to respond: ")
```

It will do the same
Bye!