# How to convert user input to upper case at real time when user enters the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
course_name = input("Enter Course name: ")
```

output: Whatever user enters is automatically converted to upper case in real time.

Comment: This would be a platform/terminal dependent solution. What terminal/OS are you using?

Comment: Ask the user to press Caps Lock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Python from showing entered input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087290/prevent-python-from-showing-entered-input)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: Convert input to upper case on screen as it is typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611748/python-convert-input-to-upper-case-on-screen-as-it-is-typed). @Tomerikoo done.